# web.config app.config and connection stringq linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have solution which has webSite and Core projects. In Core I have all model using LINQ. I there use app.Config to set paths to database in connection string used by my model.

Then I use this in my website.

Now I would like to have possibility that after deploying website on the iis to change that connections strings.

Before Linq I used web.Config to do that, now I dont know how to achieve that.

THanks for help

Comment: thought not 100% sure you still change the web.config

Comment: @snorlaks, If you have a connection string in your web.config file, the fact that you use LINQ doesn't matter, you can still change the value in the web.config.  Could you add a few more details about your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the connection string in the web.config the same way you were doing before.